# Implementing FTP Server/Client in C

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, network-programming, ftp-server

I am asked for an assignment that requires implementation of FTP protocol. I have gone through the documentation given at [RFC959](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/).

I am confused with a couple of implementation details

1)If a file needs to be transferred, what function can be used. can a simple send() function be used for a non text file.

2) Is it possible to get a good tutorial that speaks about implementing Modes and file structures, and to specify, which are essential.

hope to get a reply soon.

Comment: I think client send bytes of the file then merge everything at the end (by server)

Comment: What you can do is to devide your file in small chunks and send them one by one on the server. The server while reconstruct the entire file with all the chunks.

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes. (2) is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

FTP transfers file through a plain TCP connection, and you can transfer any kind of file with it. There is no difference between text files and binary files, they are all just sequence of bytes.

For the file transmission is sufficient to open a connection and call the `write` function many times until the entire file is transmitted (check the return value of `write` to know how many bytes it sent).

The rest of the FTP protocol is text based and is sent to a different port.

There is a [good tutorial](http://www.freefire.org/articles/ftpexample.php) on using FTP directly through [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), that can be useful to understand how things work. Understanding [active and passive mode](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) can also be useful, since you are going to implement at least one of them.

Also, use wireshark to follow a TCP stream and see the data you are sending/receiving, it can be very useful in debugging.

Comment: `write()` takes a character buffer as input. will it be possible to send an image file or any other binary file using the `write()`, do I need to open such files as `rb`, or does an `r` is enough? @fede1024

Comment: It is also given that the maximum length allowed for `write()` is `1 GB`, still is it necessary or "advisable" to send only a few bytes, say 100 or 512 bytes a time? @fede1024

Comment: A character buffer just means a buffer of bytes, you can store any value from 0 to 255 in a char (of course, it may give you weird symbols if you try to print it as an ASCII character). On Linux there is no difference if you use the `b` flag or not, but i would put it anyway because in other platforms can be different. Use a small buffer, just few Kb is ok.

Comment: To send files, you should look at [sendfile](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html)

Comment: @fede1024 The "good tutorial" link returns 404

Answer (score 1):

The protocol implementation won't give you a file structure. The protocol is here to define some rules and states.

The dev/prog part is up to you. You just need to respect the FTP protocol in order to gain the normalization and the compatibility with other client/server.

Best regards